# Put . ~/.bashrc and now prompts 2 files to edit indefinitely

Tags: bashrc

I am a beginner Ubuntu user: I ran the command `. ~/.bash_aliases` and now anytime I open Ubuntu on my windows laptop, it reads 2 files to edit, opens each of the files and I press quit every time to get back to the command line. I would initially be back in the command line, but would be brought back to edit the tiles indefinitely until I closed the prompt. Closing the prompt and reopening it, it would make me edit the 2 files and then let me go back to the command line.

How do I stop Ubuntu from doing this?

Edit: There is nothing in the bash_aliases file, I moved all the content to the bashrc file. 
This is the contents of the bashrc file:

```
 BASE16_SHELL=$HOME/.config/base16-shell/ 
[ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -s $BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh ] && eval "$($BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh)"

export PS1="\e[95m\w\e[0m\$ "
alias ls="ls --color=auto"         
alias update="sudo apt-get install"
alias compile=". ~/.bashrc"
alias alias="vi ~/.bash_aliases"
alias thiscomp="cd /mnt/c/Users/name/Documents"
```

Comment: Can we get the contents of your .bash_aliases file?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1025936/edit) your original question above and add the contents of the `.bash_aliases` file. Please use the { } icon above the edit window to format the code copied and pasted in the original question.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu on Bash on Windows? ie WSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the line:

```
alias alias="vi ~/.bash_aliases"
```

Also probably delete the line:

```
alias compile=". ~/.bashrc"
```

Comment: Should i `source ~/.bashrc` it after deleting it?

Comment: @hello1094 Don't delete `~/.bashrc`. There is no need to source it, it is automatic when you open a terminal window.

Comment: Sorry, i meant after deleting the 2 alias lines

Comment: The existing alias will stay in place if you resource `.bashrc`. Close the terminal and reopen it.